# How to display different element from different array in different section in single table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table with 3 sections, all three sections have different number of rows. The cell values should populate from different array's. 
So how should i find out which section is it in method cellForRowAtIndexPath:???

Please help!!!

```
Code:

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    currentSection = section;
    int number = 0;
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            number = self.basic.count;
            break;
        case 1:
            number = allSectors.count;
            break;
        case 2:
            number = 1;
            break;
        default:
            number = 0;
            break;
    }

    return number;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    CGFloat fontSize = [UIFont systemFontSize];
    CGFloat smallFontSize = [UIFont smallSystemFontSize];
    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.basic objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.allSectors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"None";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}


return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `indexPath.section` to get the table section, and `indexPath.row` to get the row in that section. These properties are defined in the category `NSIndexPath (UIKitAdditions)`.

Comment: ok cool. I used this and i suppose its working but when i am trying to scroll down and see what's get displayed in the next section , it crashes. Is there any thing wrong i am doing. Please see above for code.

Comment: @Ashutosh, I don't see anything that's obviously wrong. It'd help to have the error and the line where the crash happens, but perhaps this is straying into new question territory.

Comment: Sorry...my fault. allSectors is an NSMutableArray which has NSSet inside it. Fix: cell.textLabel.text = [[self.allSectors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"SECTORNAME"];